# KQL Help: Need to trim the Datetime value

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to trim the Datetime value in KQL.

I have Timer Trigger based Azure function which runs every 30 mins

> ("0 */30 * * * *")]

I have 2 datetime columns **StartTime** and **EndTime**. I am getting the Runtimes of Azure Function by summarizing **min(StartTime)** - **max(EndTime)**.
I want the **min(StartTime)** to trimmed to the actual start time of the Azure Function.

**Example**: If the min(StartTime) Column Value is "2021-10-25 10:02:26.7630995" then the StartTime should be "2021-10-25 10:00:00.000000"

**And**

If the **min(StartTime)** Column Value is "2021-10-25 10:32:26.7630995" then the StartTime should be **"2021-10-25 10:30:00.000000"**

**My Code so far:** (I need help in line #4 )

```html
MyKustoTable | where isnotempty(RunID) and RunID > 41
| project RunID, CollectionTime, IngestionTime = ingestion_time()-30m
| summarize StartTime = min(CollectionTime), EndTime = max(IngestionTime) by RunID
| extend RBACDurationInMins = case((EndTime - StartTime)/1m > 30, "Trimmed StartTime", StartTime) 
| extend RBACDurationInMins = (EndTime - StartTime)/1m, ResourceType = "RBAC"
| project ResourceType, RunID, StartTime, EndTime, RBACDurationInMins
| sort by RunID desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the `bin()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction

> *if the min(StartTime) Column Value is "2021-10-25 10:02:26.7630995" then the StartTime should be "2021-10-25 10:00:00.000000"*

> *If the min(StartTime) Column Value is "2021-10-25 10:32:26.7630995" then the StartTime should be "2021-10-25 10:30:00.000000"*

```
print dt1 = datetime(2021-10-25 10:02:26.7630995), 
      dt2 = datetime(2021-10-25 10:32:26.7630995)
| project result1 = bin(dt1, 30m),
          result2 = bin(dt2, 30m)
```

| result1 | result2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-25 10:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-25 10:30:00.0000000 |

Comment: Thanks a ton @Yoni. bin() function works like a charm.